# MWFeedParser check if data is new

Tags: ios, objective-c, rss

I'm currently trying to make a RSS like iPhone application using MWFeedParser https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser to parse my xml feed. Currently I'm trying to implement a background fetch into my app. When there are new items the user gets a local notification. I'm having a hard time checking if there are new entries in my RSS feed I'm currently using the code below. parsedItems is an NSArray which is automatically filled when `[feedparser parse]` is called. Now the problem is that parsedItems.count always returns zero although I refresh my feed. Any ideas?

In my app delegate I have the following function:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{

    NewsTableViewController *viewController = [[NewsTableViewController alloc] init];
    [viewController fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler:^(UIBackgroundFetchResult result) {
        completionHandler(result);
    }];
}
```

And in my NewsTableViewController class I have the function:

```
-(void)fetchNewDataWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    NSArray *oldItems;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *objectData = [defaults objectForKey:@"parsedItems"];
    if(objectData != nil)
    {
        oldItems = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:objectData];
        oldItems = [oldItems sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                               [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date"
                                                                                    ascending:NO]]];
    }

    // Refresh data
    [feedParser stopParsing];
    [parsedItems removeAllObjects];
    [feedParser parse];

    NSLog(@"old:%lu", oldItems.count);
    NSLog(@"new:%lu", parsedItems.count);
    NSLog(@"ding:%lu", self.itemsToDisplay.count);
    if (parsedItems.count == oldItems.count) {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
        NSLog(@"No data.");
    }
    else {
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber++;
        [self sendNotification];
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

        [defaults setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:parsedItems] forKey:@"parsedItems"];
        [defaults synchronize];

        NSLog(@"New data was fetched.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about 'outsourcing' this job to services like [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm making an app for someone who wants to put the RSS on their own website not uploading it to services like that :(